# Application crash when setting alertviewstyle

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm trying to use the `alertviewstyle` to use the text input from a user.
When I show the `alertview` without changing the style, it works.

When I change the style to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` I get this error:

> error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file.

I am using the follow code:

```
nameAlertView =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[langFile objectForKey:@"sequenceTitel"]
                               message:[langFile objectForKey:@"sequenceTitel"]
                              delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:[langFile objectForKey:@"cancel"]
                     otherButtonTitles:[langFile objectForKey:@"save"], nil];

nameAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

[nameAlertView show];
[nameAlertView release];
```

**Edit**

I'm using iOS 5.1 and I had the follow feedback from debugger:

> Training Tool(2332,0x3f080d98) malloc: *** mmap(size=1342177280) failed (error code=12)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>   ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

---

It's strange because sometimes it works when completing the same actions in my view

Comment: are you sure the langFile have a enough data ?

Comment: i m sure about that, that is an problem in your langFile

Comment: When I'm using other just text @"text", it's just the same!

Comment: what virsion of iOS is used ?

Comment: then this was definitely work because i try this this was working for me.

Comment: are you using ARC in your project

Answer (score 0):

You'll find out what the object is when you break in the debugger. Just look up the call stack and you will find where you free (or release) it. That will tell you which object it is.

The easiest way to set the breakpoint is to:

```
Goto Run -> Show -> Breakpoints (Alt-Command-B)
Scroll to the bottom of the list and add the symbol malloc_error_break
```

Comment: It's strange. Because sometimes it works when completing the same actions in my view & sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've met the same problem when setting the deployment target to 4.X since this style property is only supported in ios5. Make sure "deployment target" is 5.1 even if your device is ios 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Do not release the UIAlertView right after you display it.Release it inside the delegate callback.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today, I searched for [this thing](http://www.openradar.me/20615507) , it solves my problem, I hope you can answer confusion.
It means that because before setting alert.alertviewstyle, your keyboard is open resulting in the problem, when I turn off the keyboard before setting alertviewstyle, and it's normal.
This is the iOS 9 before a bug, iOS 9 fix it.